# how do I send data from KnockOut to Php for MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, knockout.js

I can get my data to show properly from KnockOut; however, I cannot figure out a good way to get it the the PHP and have PHP prepare the data for mySQL:

From my form page I can trigger the data to display on submit, no problem:

```
var json =   ko.utils.stringifyJson( this.Stuff );     
alert("This is what I wanna save: \n" + json );
```

But, say I want to send it to a php file to write it to mySql--what do I do next?

```
ko.utils.postJson( $("form")[0], this.Stuff );
// or
$.get( "_php/savetodb.php" , json );
```

...And when the PHP page receives the JSON formatted data, then what?

Every solution I have seen online has basically said "you can do it." but not what it is that I would be doing.

The path I am trying ( from what I have read, this is the preferred path) is:
FORM DATA -> KNOCKOUT -> ENCODE JSON -> PHP -> DECODE JSON -> MYSQL

Comment: If you use jQuery instead of ko.utils.postJson, make sure you use $.post rather than the $.get you used in your question.

Answer (score 4):

There were some *helpful* answers out there-- mostly they boiled down to "Hey, why don't you read the documentation?"

For the first part where I am trying to send data to PHP via JSON I found this link helpful:
[[factsandpeople.com]](http://www.factsandpeople.com/facts-mainmenu-5/26-html-and-javascript/89-jquery-ajax-json-and-php)

so the code that is working for me (well for testing) is: HTML

```
<form name="info" action="" method="get">
    First : <input type="text" name="first" value="Sandra" size="23"><br>
    Last : <input type="text" name="last" value="Grastlath"  size="23"><br>

<input type="button" name="valid" value="Validate" onclick="validate()">

<div id="fullresponse"><span/></div>
<div id="sales1Lastname"><span/></div>
```

Next was the java script:

```
var data = 
    { 
         "sales": [ 
             { "firstname" : "John", "lastname" : "Brown" },
             { "firstname" : "Marc", "lastname" : "Johnson" }
          ] // end of sales array
    }
function validate()
    {
        var p = document.forms['info'];

        data['sales'].push( { "firstname" : document.forms['info']['first'].value , "lastname" : document.forms['info']['last'].value } );

        var dataString = JSON.stringify(data);
        $.get('parser.php', { data: dataString}, showResult, "text");
    }

function showResult(res)
    {
        $("#fullresponse").html("<br><b>Full response: </b><br>" +res);
        var obj = JSON.parse(res);
        var l = obj.sales.length - 1;
        $("#sales1Lastname").html("<br><b>Lastname of sales[1]: </b><br>" +obj.sales[l].lastname);
    }
```

And now the PHP:

```
    $logFile = 'logFile';
    $req = $_REQUEST['data'];

    $res = json_decode(stripslashes( $req ), true);

    error_log("result: ".$req.", res=".json_encode($res), 3, $logFile);

    error_log(", sales1_lastname: ".$res['sales'][1]['lastname'], 3, $logFile);

    error_log("\n", 3, $logFile);

    header("Content-type: text/plain");

    echo json_encode($res);

    ?>
```

Like I said, this was really simple, but I am at a place now where I can at least follow all the *great* advice I was given... and read the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP you need to:

1. Decode the JSON using [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)
2. Execute an `INSERT` on your MySql Database: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: How is this helpless, because I didn't copy and paste copyrighted samples in to this site?  His PHP answer includes exactly what I linked to, using `json_decode` and his answer doesn't include MySql insert help, mine does.

Comment: I added code and sighted my source. 
Telling someone to read the documentation isn't exactly helping. It is the equivalent of asking for help in an electronics store and having someone read the box to you.
Also, you weren't the only person who posted, just the only post that is showing.

Comment: If you need additional help (you didn't indicate how much you needed in the question, I appologize) then you simply comment on the question or answer and ask for additional info, this wasn't worth a downvote, I could have easily added to this if someone simply asked, they did not.  Your question does not indicate what level of PHP or MySql experience you have.  Initial posts of questions are the beginning not the end, this site is like wikipedia, stuff can be improved, but if an initial wrong answer is immediately downvoted what incentive do I have to ever help you again?